# First load css and then load page content angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Please visit this site:
[Nadpco](http://www.nadpco.com/#/Home?lang=en)

At first load this page, maybe less than one second, you see something like this picture:
[image]

and then every thing will OK.

Likely this is why that, at first content loaded and then css load.

How to I resolve this problem.

Notablyو I used AngularJs and Bootstrap for create this site.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show code where you are attaching css and js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your stylesheets is inside the body. You need to move it inside the head instead.

**From:**

```
<body><div ng-controller="mainLayoutController" class="ng-scope">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>مشاور سرمایه گذاری نوآوران امین</title>
    <link href="/Content/css?v=4sokSQu85ZOhWi6vSDkriSC11saVOXIr5e8wfPjGMSM1" rel="stylesheet">

    <link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2">
    <link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2">
```

**To:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>مشاور سرمایه گذاری نوآوران امین</title>
    <link href="/Content/css?v=4sokSQu85ZOhWi6vSDkriSC11saVOXIr5e8wfPjGMSM1" rel="stylesheet">

    <link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2">
    <link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use css in head and js files at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should put links to styles in head tag:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=4sokSQu85ZOhWi6vSDkriSC11saVOXIr5e8wfPjGMSM1" rel="stylesheet">
<link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Bootstrap-Less/custom-less/main.min.css?v=2">
<link ng-href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/LTR-Views/News/News.min.css?v=2">
```

Also you should hide templates. It's possible by hiding content and when angular startups to show it. You can try to use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive or hide and show content with css classes.